# Как в blender уменьшить количество полигонов в модели не изменяя ее форму?

Tags: 3d, blender

Очень много полигонов на модели из-за модификатора `subdivision surface`. Очень сильно тормозит сцена. Как их уменьшить не изменяя форму модели?

Answer (score -1):

Ну ты можешь просто поставить меньше итераций для вьюпорта или вообще отключить его, пока работаешь.